# bash environment - pasting strings with "special" characters

Tags: bash, copy-paste, settings

I'm using an application and I need to paste a string into the app...
e.g
ãµÜÇæ¢üäÄøqò

When I login with bash shell it's impossible to paste the string with the special characters.
If I change the shell to sh it works fine.

Does someone knows what/if there are any variabels that I must set in bash to get it work in bash?

Comment: What's the output of `locale`? What's the output of `hd` after you've pasted that data in it and pressed Ctrl-D twice? What's your terminal or terminal emulator?

Comment: Do you have a `"set convert-meta on"` setting in `/etc/inputrc` or `~/.inputrc`?

Comment: And last, do you have `set input-meta on` or `set meta-flag on` or `set output-meta on` in `/etc/inputrc` or `~/.inputrc`? Or for short, what the output of `grep -i meta /etc/inputrc ~/.inputrc`? Or even better: `bind -v | grep meta`

Comment: The following links may also be helpful... [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45002299/why-special-characters-added-when-to-copy-and-paste-from-leafpad-into-console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45002299/why-special-characters-added-when-to-copy-and-paste-from-leafpad-into-console)
[https://cirw.in/blog/bracketed-paste](https://cirw.in/blog/bracketed-paste)

Answer (score 5):

Most probably, your readline configuration doesn't enable the `input-meta` variable or has `convert-meta` enabled.

Add:

```
set input-meta on
set output-meta on
set convert-meta off
```

To your `~/.inputrc`.

Comment: Thank's a lot, I didn't expect an answer so soon ...
I added this lines into /etc/inputrc file 
set input-meta on
set output-meta on
set convert-meta off

It works fine now